# simple way to display data in a .txt file on a webpage?

Tags: html, iframe

Working on a project, one of the webpages will display a list of people (specifically, a list of people from a graduation class that haven't been located yet).
Instead of manually updating these lists in tables which is a boneheaded Web 1.0 way of doing it, I'd like to take the submitted list of names, convert them to a simple .txt list, and then display that list on the webpage.

So far, the easist way to do this is to use an iframe element... only thing is, I cannot (or don't know how to) apply any text styling to the contents of the iframe. I've published a sample of what I've been able to accomplish here: http://dongarber.com/test//helpus-iframetest.html

The default font is courier, and the client probably ain't gonna be too keen on it.
Is there a better way to do this, that's doesn't require ASP.NET or a database?

```
#list  p {
    font: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}

...


    <p>Help us locate all of our classmates from the High School class of 1961. If  you know&nbsp;where they live&nbsp;or their e-mail addresses contact the Reunion Committee.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="list"><p><iframe src="missingmen.txt" width=200 height=400 frameborder=0 ></iframe></p></div>



  </div>
```

Comment: What *can* you use? This would be a one-liner in any server-side language.

Comment: Or even using [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Easy way:

- Rename `missingmen.txt` to `missingmen.html`.
- Add a single line to the top of `missingmen.html`:
  `<link href="txtstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
- Create a file called `txtstyle.css`, and add to it a line like this:
  `html, body {font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}`

Comment: Oh dear... that sounds like a lot more work than doing it this way ;-)

Comment: Perhaps - the plus for the solution in my original answer is that it's *very easy* to understand and implement.

Comment: You can use `html, body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap; }` to make line breaks work.

Comment: The actually easiest way is described in an answer below using the <object> tag

Comment: @Hobbamok: This _10 year old_ question asks for a way to customise the font, I don't think that's possible with `<object>`. Also, if you wanted to do it like that, there's almost no reason to use `<object>` instead of a standard `<iframe>`. It's also strange to downvote a working answer just because you like another answer more, just upvote that one instead.

Comment: @thirtydot yeah it's 10 years old but near the top when you google showing txt files within a website or similar. And CSS can apply a font to <object> content as well. Btw. one of the reasons could be the absolute horror it is to read local files for an iframe, which object has no problem with

Comment: @Hobbamok: CSS alone cannot style the inner content ("change the font family") of an `iframe` or an `object` embed, or show me how it's done. For a local text file, there's no difference between `iframe` and `object` in modern browsers, or again: show an example.

Comment: @thirtydot https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52027/problem-loading-a-local-file-in-html-using-the-iframe-tag tl:dr:  a chrome security feature won't let you load iframes from local files. Same for firefox. There is your difference. an hour wasted on iframes vs it works after 5 min with object

Comment: @Hobbamok: I don't think it's true that it's different. I've just tested with a HTML file opened as a local file, and both `iframe` and `object` work for me loading a local text file in a different path (if I instead load the same HTML file through a local web server, neither `iframe` nor `object` works). That 2013 question does not really support your case, it mentions nothing about `object` vs `iframe`, it just has a very confused guy. I suspect you're wrong, but am happy to be shown otherwise.

Answer (score 30):

In more recent browsers code like below may be enough.

```html
<object data="https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt" width="300" height="200">
Not supported
</object>
```

Comment: This is the actual answer! 10/10. Easy to implement, works right away, no fiddling around.

Comment: For the part with changing the font etc: CSS classes

Answer (score 20):

I find that if I try things that others say do not work, it's how I learn the most.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>README.txt</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="list">
  <p><iframe src="README.txt" frameborder="0" height="400"
      width="95%"></iframe></p>
</div>
```

This worked for me. I used the yellow background-color that I set in the stylesheet.

```
#list  p {
    font: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: yellow ;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to throw the contents of the file onto the screen you can try using PHP.

```
<?php
    $myfilename = "mytextfile.txt";
    if(file_exists($myfilename)){
      echo file_get_contents($myfilename);
    }
?>
```

---

Comment: Use `include`, much more efficient!

Answer (score 6):

How are you converting the submitted names to "a simple .txt list"?  During that step, can you instead convert them into a simple HTML list or table?  Then you could wrap that in a standard header which includes any styling you want.

Comment: Yes, I think this is close to what thirtydot suggests. Thanks and a voteup for you too!

Answer (score 4):

That's the code I use:

```
<?php   
    $path="C:/foopath/";
    $file="foofile.txt";

    //read file contents
    $content="
        <h2>$file</h2>
            <code>
                <pre>".htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("$path/$file"))."</pre>
            </code>";

    //display
    echo $content;
?>
```

Keep in mind that if the user can modify $path or $file (for example via $_GET or $_POST), he/she will be able to see all your source files (danger!)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot style a text file, it must be HTML

Answer (score 0):

Most easy and simple way to show file on your web page

> Here is a screenshot. You can see here a pdf and txt file.

[Sample Screenshot of TXT file rendered on HTML using iframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exAgA.png)

```
<iframe
    src="full_file_path_here"
    frameBorder="0"
    class=""
    scrolling="auto"
    height="100%"
    width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -7):

You can add it as script file.
save the txt file with js suffix

in the head section add

```html
<script src="fileName.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why? That doesn't even make sense