# Display text file in HTML

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to display the content of a text file in html without using ajax, javascript ecc.
but possibly css and html.
I have a slideshow of images and depending on the image you select, the content of the text file should appear under the photo. I know how to associate the text file with the photo and it should work, but how can I can display the content of the txt file in the web page?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you have an example?
What is the reason you do not want to use JavaScript? 
And do you get the text to show up on the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple way to display data in a .txt file on a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642681/simple-way-to-display-data-in-a-txt-file-on-a-webpage)

Comment: Can you not use Javascript for this, or are you choosing not to? What you are describing is not the ideal way to display captions for a slideshow. You should really code the captions into the same file and then use Javascript to show/hide them depending on what image is being displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

```html
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/reputation"></iframe>
```

> **Edit:** Stack Overflow no longer allows `<iframe>`'s to a different domain, so I switched to using `//stackoverflow.com/reputations` for the demos

This is probably more what you are looking for(Image with text below it):

```css
iframe{
    border:none;
    width:400px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/reputation"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to an iframe the  tag does the trick well.

[nikolay_turpitko's answer to a similar question does it quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52380553/8326972)

[Below is his answer copied directly]

In more recent browsers code like below may be enough.

```html
<object data="https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt" width="300" height="200">
Placeholder Text
</object>
```