# What is the HTML code to bring in words from a separate .txt file?

Tags: html, streaming, twitch

I am trying to code for a Twitch stream overlay using HTML/CSS and a Browser Source Plugin. I have everything coded OK (animation, basic text, colors, etc.), except I cannot seem to get text from a seperate .txt file to appear within my HTML file. This text is within a file named *most_recent_follower* and the .txt file updates whenever I get a new follower (with the Twitch name of the follower).

All I want is my HTML file to pull this name from the .txt file. What is the coding for this? I tried *(object)*, and this did pull the name correctly, however, then I could not edit the style of the text.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642681/simple-way-to-display-data-in-a-txt-file-on-a-webpage

Comment: Thank you for posting that link. However, it was unable to assist. The top answer has me renaming the files to HTML format, which I do not think I can do. For the PHP answer, I cant seem to get the PHP code to properly pull the words from the .txt. I am using Chrome FYI. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why exactly can't you rename a file from `.txt` to `.html`?

Comment: The files communicate with Twitch Alerts (StreamLabels) where the files update with new follower, donations, subscribers, etc. Seems that updating these files messes with this link.

Comment: In that case, you should to use another language; HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. Try JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the continued replies. I have spent the morning researching Javascript and I still cant get the command to work. For simplistic reasons, I now have a file named sample.txt with the contents of Sample File. What would the complete string of Java or HTML commands be to display this on a webpage and properly update if I update the sample.txt file?

Comment: First off: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript at all. Those are two entirely different languages. Also, HTML can't just display a text file, nor can it update it. HTML is a **markup** language only, you can't program with it. You will **have** to do that in JavaScript, if it needs to run in a browser.

In JavaScript, you could probably do something like `fetch("your-text-file.txt").then(response => response.text().then(text => document.querySelector("twitch-tipper").textContent = text));`, assuming there's an HTML element named `<twitch-tipper/>` that contains the current tipper.