# Unable to display the contents of a text file in an html webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning how to use html and javascript, and I've been trying to create a html webpage that gets the contents of a text file, info.txt, and displays it on the webpage as soon as the webpage is opened.

My problem is that the contents of the text file will not show up on the webpage. I've tried opening my html file on Chrome and FireFox, but the info.txt's contents won't show up. I'm storing the text and html files in the same folder.

I've attached my html code and info.txt. If anyone could give me some pointers on how to resolve this, I'd really appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Info</h2>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>

function read_file() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var e = document.getElementById('info');
      e.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'info.txt', true);
  xhttp.send();
}
read_file();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

info.txt:

```
Dan, Green Tea
Lola, Earl Grey
De, Matcha
Pearl, Coffee
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any html element with an id="info".

`var e = document.getElementById('info');`

This is trying to find that element with the id, but there isn't one.

I think what you need to do is create some sort of element, maybe a paragraph element that has this id.
`<p id="info"></p>`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added the <p id="info"></p> before my script tag, but I'm still not able to see the contents of my text file on the webpage. Do I need to call my read_file function inside the paragraph tags?

Comment: You can try debugging this issue using the developer console (I'm assuming you haven't used this yet). If you're on Chrome, navigate to Developer Tools and bring up the console tab. There are other ways to render the contents of .txt file in html (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642681/simple-way-to-display-data-in-a-txt-file-on-a-webpage), but I also understand that your primary goal might be learning Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I checked out the developer console, and it looks like I have a problem with the CORS policy which is why the contents of my text file isn't showing up.